# Статус "В наличии" на витрине товара Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

В "Товарах" можно изменить статус товара на "Нет в наличии". Данный статус появляется в карточке товара и исчезает кнопка "Добавить в корзину". Как отобразить этот статус в витрине товара (в подкатегории) под каждым товаром?

Comment: Пошто парня заминусовали? Нормальные вопросы. Щас отвечу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Код такой в function.php

```
function action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item() {
    global $product;
    if ($product->stock_status == 'instock') {
        echo '<div class="my_quantity">В наличии: ' . $product->stock . '</div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div class="my_quantity">' . 'Нет в наличии' . '</div>';
    }
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item');
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло! Еше дописал в доп стилях `.my_quantity{ color:green; } .my_quantity_none{ color: red; }`.

Comment: Спасибо )) выручили. Но вот момент: статус появляется на фотографии товара. А как можно регулировать расположение. Если например нужно поставить его после цены или перед наименованием товара?

Comment: а куда это воткнуть чтоб оно работало?

Comment: @Morpheus как обычно - в functions.php дочерней темы. Или в свой плагин.

Answer (score 0):

У меня отображал только "Нет в наличии". Чуть переделал строку, теперь нормально:

```
function action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item() {
    global $product;
    if ($product->stock_status == 'instock') {
        echo '<div class="my_quantity">' . 'В наличии' . '</div>'; 
    } else {
        echo '<div class="my_quantity">' . 'Нет в наличии' . '</div>';
    }
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item');
```