# Статус “Нет в наличии” на витрине для вариативного товара Woocommerce?

Tags: php, woocommerce

Вариативный товар имеет статус "Нет в наличии". Как отобразить этот статус в витрине товара под каждым товаром?

Я нашел много ответов на этот вопрос, но все они касаются простого товара, например [Статус “В наличии” на витрине товара Woocommerce?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/662168/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%81-%D0%92-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0-woocommerce)

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел ответ на свой вопрос. Код ([ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/662168/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%81-%D0%92-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0-woocommerce)) одинаково работает и для простого товара и для вариативного. Моя проблема заключалась в том, что я вариации просто скрывал используя массив

```
$data = [
'visible' => false
 ];
 $wooсommerce->put("products/{$v1->id}/variations/{$v2->id}", $data);
```

Соответственно нужно мне было использовать для каждой вариации массив:

```
$data = [
'in_stock' => false
];
```